# Не получается настроить работу библиотеки curse.h в Visual Studio для языка Си

Tags: c, библиотеки, curses

После создания проекта в Visual Studio под Си (выбрал пункт компилировать как код Си)
По гайду подключил curses.h 
Но при компиляции выдает ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wgetch referenced in function _main Laba 16 C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Laba 16\Laba 16\Source.obj 1   


 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__stdscr    Laba 16 C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Laba 16\Laba 16\Source.obj 1
```

Comment: Текст ошибки переделайте в текстовый вид. Трудно читать, и искать по тексту ошибки.

Comment: нужно подлинковать библиотеку.

Comment: @nick_n_a  `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wgetch referenced in function _main Laba 16 C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Laba 16\Laba 16\Source.obj 1`

Comment: @KoVadim можете пожалуйста объяснить,что значит подлинковать библиотеку

Comment: Под вопросом есть ссылка-кнопка "править".

Comment: Большинство библиотек для с/с++ идут в виде h файлы и библиотека (в винде - файлы с расширением .a). И в настройках проекта нужно указать этот файл.

Comment: @KoVadim но у меня нет такого файла в скачанной библиотеке
Только 2 хедера(curse.h и panel.h), pdcurses.lib и pdcurses.dll

Comment: pdcurses.lib поможет. Ищите в настройках проекта, где либы добавлять.

Comment: Да длл тоже поможет, попробуйте добавить её в проект

Comment: lib это статистическая линковка, DLL это динамическая линковка